# Calling PHP function with arguments remotely

Tags: php

I have a scenario where in our php file accepts parameters from the command line.

For example we say,

```
php test.php 'hello'
```

Now the above runs on command prompt. Suppose now we want to invoke this from client end however ofcourse i do not want the System system call as that would be a bad design, i just want to directly call the function which accepts parameters from the client end and ofcourse client can be anything maybe .Net or PHP so how can I caccomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the System system call. Why do consider it bad design? Invoking external programs is always platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script on a web server and accept the argument via HTTP GET or POST.

It would look something like `http://hostname/test.php?argument=hello`. Then, in your `test.php`script, pass the `$_GET['argument']` to your function:

`myfunction($_GET['argument']);`

Don't forget to sanitize the input!

Answer (score 0):

you may use a function that will manage command line argiments:

`$param_1 = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : null;
if ($param_1 == 'function1')
  function1()
elseif...`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper script that puts GET parameters from your client into the command line argument array.

Let's say your client makes a request like:

```
hostname/testWrapper.php?params[]=hello&params[]=goodbye
```

Your wrapper script testWrapper.php could then look like

```
<?php
  $params = $_GET['params'];

  foreach ($params as $i => $param)
    $_SERVER['argv'][$i + 1] = $param;

  $_SERVER['argc'] = count($_GET['params'] + 1);

  include ('test.php');
?>
```

This assumes that your test.php uses `$_SERVER['argv/argc']`to read command line arguments. It may use `$argv` and `$argc` instead (if 'register_argc_argv' is enabled in your php.ini), in which case you just use those in your wrapper script instead of `$_SERVER[...]`.

Notice that we have to insert the parameters with an offset of 1 (i.e. `$params[0]` becomes `$_SERVER['argv'][1]`. This is because when the script is called from the command line, the first parameter `$_SERVER['argv'][0]` is the script name.

Lastly, unless you are absolutely sure that your test.php sanitizes the parameters, you have to do it in the wrapper script.